# Django / python: how to get the value of a text field and store it into a variable

Tags: django

I am new to django and python: I would like to get the text the user types into a text field and store it into a variable when they submit button a form. The text is 5 characters long.
This is my form:

```
<h4>Enter your ID</h4>
<form action="/login/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="kodikos" id="kodikos" maxlength="5" placeholder = "Password">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<ul id="results">
{% for user in data1 %}            
    <li>  ID: {{user.emp_no}} - Last name: {{user.last_name}} </li>              
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to get the `kodikos` value and compare it with `data1`. I can't find how to get this value. Do I need Javascript? I tried it but still can't get this value. Also, how can all this happen after the user hits the submit button?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how forms and Django work. Please visit [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/) to read up on these. It is done through GET and POST requests; please play around with these concepts. If you want to compare the values in the browser without going back to Django, yes, you need javascript.

Comment: Of which field you want ```kodikos``` to compare with ```data1```?

Comment: I know that the GET request gets the value i enter into the text field when i hit the submit button because i can see on the url this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?kodikos=45  But what i want is to be able to store 45 (the value i entered) into a variable so i can check if this value is in data1 (data1 is a JSON file that is returned from a REST web service call)